# Redirecting an internal path to a virtual host

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-rewrite, virtual, hosts

I have been working on a drupal test site for a while, which has a bunch of virtual hosts set up like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin email@example.com
DocumentRoot "/path/to/root"
ServerName testsite1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I have been using a modified host file to view each of these test sites, along the lines of:

```
12.0.0.1 localhost
20.02.2.22 testsite1.example.com
20.02.2.22 testsite2.example.com
20.02.2.22 testsite3.example.com
```

This has worked fine, however now I need to send the sites over to some people remotely who are not technical enough to modify their own host files and see it the way I do.

Is there a way I could set up Apache so that the url "http://20.02.2.22/testsite1" would forward to testsite1.example.com internally? I am using Drupal, and the site setup needs to see the "testsite1.example.com" so that it can correctly choose the instance to select. I have been looking through apache rewrite, but I am a bit of a newb at this so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

testsite1.example.com will only be resolved on your machine, so you cannot redirect. You can set up proxy with mod_proxy. Hope this works for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin email@example.com
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/root"
  ServerName testsite1.example.com
  ServerAlias 20.02.2.22
  <Location /testsite1/>
    ProxyPass http://testsite1.example.com/ 
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This came close, but instead of simply sending the request internally, it causes the browser to request testsite1.example.com, which doesn't exist. Thanks though, mod_proxy is a great direction it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The way I show my local test sites is a combination of Dynamic DNS and port-forwarding.

Internally, my Drupal site is at [my machine ip] or localhost.

I setup a free dynamic dns name to my IP and then on my router, accept incoming requests on port to route to [my machine ip]

That way, they can see yoursite.dyndns.com, but its looking at your local copy.

Answer (score -1):

Why you just don't buy a new domain name and point it to your server IP address...
Or there are free domain solutions like:

```
http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en
or
http://dyn.com/dns/
```

If you wanna buy new domain, i recommending you this one, cheap and quality service: http://server2.elite7hackers.us/recommend.php?site=godaddy